# How is Wait() functionality Implemented

Tags: multithreading, winapi, unix, linux-kernel, win32-process

How are wait (Eg: WaitForSingleObject) functions implemented internally in Windows or any OS? 
How is it any different from a spin lock?

Does the CPU/hardware provide special functionality to do this?

Comment: You can find out more from books on OS design. Specifically for Windows you have Microsoft Windows Internals by Mark Russinovich.

Answer (score 1):

Hazy view of What's Going On follows... Focusing on IO mainly.

**Unix / Linux / Posix**

The Unix equivalent, select(), epoll(), and similar have been implemented in various ways. In the early days the implementations were rubbish, and amounted to little more than busy polling loops that used up all your CPU time. Nowadays it's much better, and takes no CPU time whilst blocked.

They can do this I think because the device driver model for devices like Ethernet, serial and so forth has been designed to support the select() family of functions. Specifically the model must allow the kernel to tell the devices to raise an interrupt when something has happened. The kernel can then decide whether or not that will result in a select() unblocking, etc etc. The result is efficient process blocking.

**Windows**

<del>In Windows the WaitfFor when applied to asynchronous IO is completely different. You actually have to start a thread reading from an IO device, and when that read completes (note, not starts) you have that thread return something that wakes up the WaitFor. That gets dressed up in object.beginread(), etc, but they all boil down to that underneath.</del>

<del>This means you can't replicate the select() functionality in Windows for serial, pipes, etc. But there is a select function call for sockets. Weird.</del>

<del>To me this suggests that the whole IO architecture and device driver model of the Windows kernel can drive devices only by asking them to perform an operation and blocking until the device has completed it. There would seem to be no truly asynchronous way for the device to notify the kernel of events, and the best that can be achieved is to have a separate thread doing the synchronous operation for you. I've no idea how they've done select for sockets, but I have my suspicions.</del>

**CYGWIN, Unix on Windows**

When the cygwin guys came to implement their select() routine on Windows they were horrified to discover that it was impossible to implement for anything other than sockets. What they did was for each file descriptor passed to select they would spawn a thread. This would poll the device, pipe, whatever waiting for the available data count to be non zero, etc. That thread would then notify the thread that is actually calling select() that something had happened. This is very reminiscent of select() implementations from the dark days of Unix, and is massively inefficient. But it does work.

<del>I would bet a whole 5 new pence that that's how MS did select for sockets too.</del>

**My Experience Thus Far**

<del>Windows' WaitFors... are fine for operations that are guaranteed to complete or proceed and nice fixed stages, but are very unpleasant for operations that aren't (like IO). Cancelling an asynchronous IO operation is deeply unpleasant. The only way I've found for doing it is to close the device, socket, pipe, etc which is not always what you want to do.</del>

**Attempt to Answer the Question**

The hardware's interrupt system supports the implementation of select() because it's a way for the devices to notify the CPU that something has happened without the CPU having to poll / spin on a register in the device.

Unix / Linux uses that interrupt system to provide select() / epoll() functionality, and also incorporates purely internal 'devices' (pipes, files, etc) into that functionality.

<del>Windows' equivalent facility, WaitForMultipleObjects() fundamentally does not incorporate IO devices of any sort, which is why you have to have a separate thread doing the IO for you whilst you're waiting for that thread to complete. The interrupt system on the hardware is (I'm guessing) used solely to tell the device drivers when a read or write operation is complete. The exception is the select() function call in Windows which operates only on sockets, not anything else.</del>

<del>A big clue to the architectural differences between Unix/Linux and Windows is that a PC can run either, but you get a proper IO-centric select() only on Unix/Linux.</del>

**Guesswork**

<del>I'm guessing that the reason Windows has never done a select() properly is that the early device drivers for Windows could in no way support it, a bit like the early days of Linux.</del>

<del>However, Windows became very popular quite early on, and loads of device drivers got written against that (flawed?) device driver standard.</del>

<del>If at any point MS had thought "perhaps we'd better improve on that" they would have faced the problem of getting everyone to rewrite their device drivers, a massive undertaking. So they decided not to, and instead implemented the separate IO thread / WaitFor... model instead. This got promoted by MS as being somehow superior to the Unix way of doing things. And now that Windows has been that way for so long I'm guessing that there's no one in MS who perceives that Things Could Be Improved.</del>

==EDIT==

I have since stumbled across [Named Pipes - Asynchronous Peeking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919373/c-sharp-named-pipe-asynchronous-peeking). This is fascinating because it would seem (I'm very glad to say) to debunk pretty much everything I'd thought about Windows and IO. The article applies to pipes, though presumably it would also apply to any IO stream.

It seems to hinge on starting an asynchronous read operation to read zero bytes. The read will not return until there are some bytes available, but none of them are read from the stream. You can therefore use something like WaitForMultipleObjects() to wait for more than one such asynchronous operation to complete.

As the comment below the accepted answer recognises this is very non-obvious in all the of the Microsoft documentation that I've ever read. I wonder about it being an unintended but useful behaviour in the OS. I've been ploughing through Windows Internals by Mark Russinovich, but I've not found anything yet.

I've not yet had a chance to experiment with this in anyway, but if it does work then that means that one can implement something equivalent to Unix's select() on Windows, so it must therefore be supported all the way down to the device driver level and interrupts. Hence the extensive strikeouts above...

Comment: It looks to me as though you don't really understand the Windows design and any variation from how it is done in *nix you deem to be inferior.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you may have noticed my prefixed caveat "Hazy view". Now, if you think you know better then why don't you make a positive contribution instead of wilfully ignoring someone else's own caveat?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the "if you can't do better, butt out" defence. I'm no authority and know when to say nothing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've come across an interesting SO answer that would seem to cast some light on the matter. If interested see the edits to my original answer.